# Convert a string to an enum

Tags: json, swift, enums, swift4, codable

I am getting data from a server and it is returned as either buy or sell as a string. I am using swifyjson to parse the json and if it is sell, I want to associate it to a variable of type OrderSide as seen below. How would I do this? I have written a function below in the enum but I feel like there is a better way to do this. In the future if there is more than just 2 cases, I don't want to have an if statement for each case. If there is anything else that can be done better here please let me know as well.

```
enum OrderSide:String  {
    case buy = "buy"
    case sell = "sell"

    static func enumFrom(string:String) -> OrderSide? {
        if string == "buy" {
            return .buy
        } else if string == "sell" {
            return .sell
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that I am using within to parse the JSON. I am getting a string from the JSON.

```
let orderSide = OrderType.enumFrom(string:swiftyJson["side"].stringValue)
```

Comment: Please show the JSON.

Comment: Your whole enum can be written simply as `enum OrderSide:String  {
    case buy, sell
}`. The compiler can infer the raw values by itself and the default initializer, `OrderSide(rawValue: String)` does exactly what your static func does...

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. If you put that as an answer, I will go ahead and mark that as the correct answer.